# No navbar at the default themes

Tags: magento-1.9, navigation, topmenu

I am new to Magento. I want to create a menu with different pages, but I don't have a navigation bar on top. How do I add a navigationbar?

**This is my topmenu.phtml:**

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
    <div class="nav-container">
        <ul id="nav">
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('top-navbar-before')->toHtml() ?>
            <?php echo $_menu ?>
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('top-navbar-after')->toHtml() ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

**Here is the static block:**

[image: **enter image description here**]

**Still no navbar. The page.xml has these lines:**

```
        <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
            <label>Navigation Bar</label>
            <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_topmenu_renderer" name="catalog.topnav.renderer" template="page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
```

Any ideas?